# В MySQL как правильно записать TimeStamp=Timestamp + DateTime

Tags: mysql, дата, преобразование-типов

В хранимой процедуре MySQL есть две переменные. В одной хранится в формате TimeStamp время регистрации,например '2020-01-15 14:30:33'. В другой переменной хранится интервал в формате DateTime, например 3 месяца '0000-03-00'.
Нужно к дате прибавить интервал.
Я это делал так

```
SET FinishTime=FinishTime+TimeRange;
```

Выражение работало для TimeRange, кратных 1, например для одного месяца '0000-01-00'
Но в общем случае FinishTime возвращал в таблицу нулевые значения в результате некорректного выполнения операции. В MySQL для этого есть функции сложения даты/времени, но конкретно к моей ситуации я не знаю как их приспособить, не хватает опыта.

Comment: Интервал НЕ может храниться в DATETIME. Там может храниться только дата/время, возможно, с некорректным значением. И в случае некорректного значения корректное извлечение из него компонентов - как минимум не гарантируется. Так что меняйте структуру хранения.

Comment: 1. В таком случае какой универсальный формат есть для хранения произвольного интервала времени в mysql?
2. Технически php получает формат DateTime как строковый. Думаю, даже в MySQL есть возможность разложить строку на месяц, день, год и провести сложение с соответствующими функциями, но это не красивое решение.

Comment: Храните интервал времени тупо в секундах в целочисленном (а если нужны доли секунды - в DECIMAL) поле. Тогда к UNIX_TIMESTAMP его можно просто прибавлять, а для полей с типом DATETIME/TIMESTAMP - используя оператор (не функцию!!!) INTERVAL.

Comment: Так ещё сложнее. В одних месяцах 31 день, в других 30, а бывают ещё 28 и 29 дней. Можно прибавлять секунды, погршеность день туда/сюда не принципиальна, но выглядит кривовато.

Answer (score 0):

Я написал вот такое решение. Оно очень громоздкое, но работает

```
BEGIN
DECLARE Time1 DATETIME;
Declare TimeRange DATETIME;

SET Time1='2020-01-01';
SET TimeRange='0000-03-02';

SELECT Time1 + INTERVAL MONTH(TimeRange) MONTH + INTERVAL DAY(TimeRange) DAY + INTERVAL YEAR(TimeRange) YEAR;

END
```

Время прибавляет правильно

Comment: Пока везёт... я говорил - *в случае некорректного значения корректное извлечение из него компонентов - как минимум не гарантируется*. Потом не жалуйтесь.